# Using My Sites Data In A List

Tags: list, my-site

Is there a way to pull data from SharePoint My Sites into a SharePoint list?

For example if I wanted to make a list of users and their phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've done this is to create a new person/group field set to display as their phone number and on item creation, set that field to the created by person via workflow. It will then show their phone number in views but the underlying data is domain\user.

Answer (score 0):

an elegant way to do this is with a Fixed Search. see http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/ for some instructions

Comment: We already have People Search up and running. Basically someone wants the data you see from People Search or My Sites (Name, Title, Number, etc) in a list view for easy printing.